# Applying a custom colour palette to charts built in SSRS and Crystal Reports

Tags: reporting-services, colors, charts, crystal-reports

I have several charts built in SSRS and Crystal Reports.  I'm trying to create a standard colour palette for them that matches our company brand standards, and want to apply a specific colour to each series value.  For example, assume the series values are:
Watermelons (always make this pink), 
Cherries (always make red), 
Grapes (always make green), and
Lemons (always make yellow).

Is there a way to do this in either SSRS or Crystal Reports (v 11)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Crystal, but for SSRS:

In the Chart definition for Values, you can set the Color property using an expression.  The best way would be to pass in an extra column in the source Dataset which gives the required Color values.  Then your Color expression can just refer to that column.

You will need to copy that Expression into to each series in each Chart object.